# A formula to Find/Replace mobile telephone numbers in text format

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007, vlookup

I have a column where I input mobile telephone numbers.  Here's sample input for Column A (text format):

```
+639154112315  
+639171214125  
+639179120519
```

I have a column (B) where I input mobile numbers (text format) that are for removal e.g.:

`+639171214125`

So Column C should display:

`+639154112315`
`+639179120519`

In Cell C I want to display the mobile numbers from Cell A but not any numbers from Cell B. I tried VLOOKUP and it doesn't work (for Cell C):

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,A:A,1,FALSE)),"",A2)
```

Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Can you post an example of input in both cells A and B?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com, not here. It's nothing to do with code.

Comment: @pnuts, it's border line. Some think that applying formula logic is like programming logic and reason enough to include an Excel formula question here. I feel that formulas are part of the Excel application and belong on SU. I'll flag to migrate and then try to answer. This way I hope that both purposes can be served.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought excel formulas can be asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a guess that by Cell you mean Column, the following (copied down as appropriate) might suit;

> =IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)=0,A1),A1,"")

*Edit* If you had merely wished to identify in ColumnA those not present in ColumnB Conditional Formatting might suit, with a formula such as `=ISNA(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)>0)`.

Comment: I've included IF in my formula `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)>0),A2,"")`
it worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post a data sample. Does column B have the actual numbers? Or a flag to remove the number of the same row?

Consider:

[image]

To build a contiguous list of numbers to be removed, add a helper column with the formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",ROW())
```

in cell C2 and copy down. Then enter this formula into cell D2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(C:C,ROW(A1))),"")
```

Copy down. The result is:

[image]

In this setup, it does not really matter what the values in column B are. It can be a "yes" or a "delete" or the actual phone number. The important bit is that the cells in column B are either empty or have a value (any value).